# run yarn command with pm2

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, pm2

I need to deploy my app on digital ocean, after installing all dependencies i ran my script yarn dev

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon --delay 10ms --exec babel-node -- app.js",
    "start": "NODE_ENV=stag nodemon --delay 10 --exec babel-node -- app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

but i want to use pm2, how can i write the command to run this yarn command with pm2.

i will require to run it with whole script to use babel-node and other params